# Are files stored on Google Drive using Android deleted if the app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Are the files saved on google-drive deleted when the application is uninstalled? I need to store files persistently even when the app is uninstalled for this I plan to store them on google-drive.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use ExternalStorage instead?

Comment: some devices don't have external storage I guess, that's why i want to use google-drive.

Regards

Comment: external data in developer context is NOT the SD card. External data is the space thatall apps can access with the correct permissions. External data is the free space on the phones storage and SD storage. All apps can access files stored there

Answer (score 0):

No they don't delete your files even if you uninstalled the application. Your files are safe as long as you maintain a Google account

Answer (score 0):

Google Files are not saved "locally" on your device and will still be available if app is uninstalled.